# How to use Design Support Library?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I added Design Support Library component from the Component store, I managed to implement some things despite the lack of documentations but I can't find or apply the `Theme.AppCompat` that this page talks about:

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamandroidsupportdesign

I also want to know if I can update this component (v 23.1.1.1) because NuGet Manager shows me new updates.
And Do I need to install other dependecies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can update that component. It can only throw and error if you have other dependencies that must be updated first.

To use `AppComapt` you must tell your `Activity` to use one and must extend `AppCompatActivity`:

```cs
[Activity(MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light")]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

You can consult [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-material-design-v7-appcompat/) more good information about Material Design and `Appcompat`.

Comment: I was reading that, but says activities must inherit from ActionBarActivity.
The thing is it wants to download older support library repository v25, but I have newer v29, how can I fix this?
And do I have to create a styles.xml file for everything to work?

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated. You should use AppCompatActivity. You can confirm here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

Comment: How to downgrade the version of the library is another question. Please open another question with that. I guess this one question is answered. I'm glad to help you in other questions. You don't have to create styles.xml. Only if you want to customize styles. If i helped you please, mark my answer as correct. Thank you

Comment: What about the `Theme.AppCompat` thing, I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: You have to download the Android Support AppComap v7 to have access to Theme.AppCompat. But when you install the Android Support Library the Android Support AppComap v7 is automaticlly installed

Comment: I was just needed to use `using Android.Support.V7.App` instead of `using Android.Support.V7.AppCompat`
Everything is working like a charm thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: Except one thing but I'll make a new question for that.

Comment: BTW do I just have to add the `Theme.AppCompat` bit over every Activity and never worry about declaring it somewhere else like the manifest or XML files?

Comment: yes you can only declare it over Activity, if you use the default Theme.AppCompat. If you want to customize you will need to add it to styles.xml